# How to use filterQuery with multiple values on cloudSearch boto3

Tags: boto3, amazon-cloudsearch

I am using boto3 and AWS cloudsearchdomain. I want to filter the results on multiple values with different combinations of boolean conditions. 
e.g. I want to get all users who are either living in 'Bengaluru' or 'Mumbai' and have an annual income of more than 20 lakhs.

I followed the https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudsearchdomain.html but didn't get any help.

I found [How to use filterQuery and queryOptions on cloudsearch boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259489/how-to-use-filterquery-and-queryoptions-on-cloudsearch-boto3) and able to perform one boolean operation on multiple values as par https://stackoverflow.com/users/7117003/petezurich comment but unable to use the combination as mention in the example.

Comment: If this question has been answered you should mark it as so

Answer (score 1):

After going through the AWS Cloud search documentation on [constructing compound queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-compound-queries.html) We can write FilterQuery on a combination of attributes as:

```
filterQuery = (and (or city:'Bengaluru' city:'Mumbai') (income:2000000))
```